# Реализовать поиск по списку из фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть `MainActivity`, в котором через `TabLayout` вывожу список станций во фрагмент. А фрагмент в свою очередь используется для вкладки.

Код фрагмента:

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment implements ItemSendId {

    private ArrayList<Radio> radioList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView radioListRecycler;
    RadiosAdapter mRadioAdapter;
    DBHeler db;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        db = new DBHeler(getContext());

        radioListRecycler = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radioListRecycler);
        mRadioAdapter = new RadiosAdapter(radioList);
        mRadioAdapter.setItemSendId(this);
        radioListRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3));
        radioListRecycler.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        radioListRecycler.setAdapter(mRadioAdapter);

        prepareRadioData();
    }

    @Override
    public void sendItemId(int id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), PlayerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void search(SearchView searchView) {

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                if (mRadioAdapter != null) mRadioAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void prepareRadioData() {
        //заполняем коллекцию
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
    }
}
```

В `MainActivity` до того как я переделал приложение, использовав `TabLayout`, поиск работал. Теперь у меня проблема. В `menu.xml` разместил компонент `SearchView`.

Код меню из `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search);
    search(searchView);
    return true;
}
```

Как обратиться из `MainActivity` к переменной `mRadioAdapter`, которая используется в том числе и в методе `search` фрагмента `TabFragment1`.

Если непонятно описал, то вот что у меня сейчас есть и что нужно получить:

Есть активити с вкладками. В первой вкладке выводятся радиостанции. Весь код для вывода станций реализован в `TabFragment1.java`. Теперь нужно, чтобы при нажатии на поиск в меню `MainActivity` осуществлялся поиск станций. Все работало до того как весь код фрагмента был в `MainActivity`, но после переноса его во фрагмент не знаю как обратиться из активити к адаптеру.

Comment: Реализуете метод `onCreateOptionsMenu` в нужном фрагменте, и там же реализовывайте поиск

Comment: пробовал. Не помогло

Comment: Из ваших слов следует, что вы всю логику из активити перенесли во фрагмент, кроме метода `onCreateOptionsMenu`, и теперь задача получить из этого метода который в активити список который во фрагменте. Если вы правильно реализуете оставшийся метож `onCreateOptionsMenu` во фрагменте, то по идее у вас не должно быть проблем.

Comment: А как правильно реализовать? Я пишу так не работает.     @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search);
        search(searchView);
    }

Comment: Если удалить метод onCreateOptionsMenu из MainActivity, то при запуске вообще меню пропадает и иконка SearchView пропадает

Comment: В `onCreate` фрагмента добавьте `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653737/oncreateoptionsmenu-inside-fragments

Comment: Сработало. Ступил я это setHasOptionsMenu(true); добавлял в сам метод onCreateOptionsMenu